# Strange VIM behaviour

Tags: vim

I recently installed a minimal version of Fedora 23 Server edition. 
I use VIM as editor, and I noticed a strange behavior when I edit any text file that is not a new file during.

Whenever I open any existent text file with VIM it is like it performs automatically the keystroke sequence `sg<esc>`. 
This is the first time that I see something like this.

NOTE: all of this is happening in an ssh session.

What could be the causes of such a strange behaviour?

If it may be of interest this is the output of vim --version.

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr  8 2016 14:13:25)
Included patches: 1-1718
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +terminfo
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +textobjects
+channel         +gettext         -mzscheme        +timers
+cindent         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clientserver    +iconv           +packages        -toolbar
-clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +job             +perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      +lua/dyn         +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xsmp
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_save
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xpm
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim74"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,relro   -Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -lnsl  -lselinux   -lncurses -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,relro  -Wl,-z,relro  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -lperl -lpthread -lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc
```

EDIT: this is the content of my /etc/vimrc file

```
if v:lang =~ "utf8$" || v:lang =~ "UTF-8$"
   set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
endif

set nocompatible        " Use Vim defaults (much better!)
set bs=indent,eol,start         " allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
"set ai                 " always set autoindenting on
"set backup             " keep a backup file
set viminfo='20,\"50    " read/write a .viminfo file, don't store more
                        " than 50 lines of registers
set history=50          " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler               " show the cursor position all the time

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands
if has("autocmd")
  augroup fedora
  autocmd!
  " In text files, always limit the width of text to 78 characters
  " autocmd BufRead *.txt set tw=78
  " When editing a file, always jump to the last cursor position
  autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") |
  \   exe "normal! g'\"" |
  \ endif
  " don't write swapfile on most commonly used directories for NFS mounts or USB sticks
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPre /media/*,/run/media/*,/mnt/* set directory=~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
  " start with spec file template
  autocmd BufNewFile *.spec 0r /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/template.spec
  augroup END
endif

if has("cscope") && filereadable("/usr/bin/cscope")
   set csprg=/usr/bin/cscope
   set csto=0
   set cst
   set nocsverb
   " add any database in current directory
   if filereadable("cscope.out")
      cs add $PWD/cscope.out
   " else add database pointed to by environment
   elseif $CSCOPE_DB != ""
      cs add $CSCOPE_DB
   endif
   set csverb
endif

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif

filetype plugin on

if &term=="xterm"
     set t_Co=8
     set t_Sb=m
     set t_Sf=m
endif

" Don't wake up system with blinking cursor:
" http://www.linuxpowertop.org/known.php
let &guicursor = &guicursor . ",a:blinkon0"
```

Comment: Rather than linking to pastbin, can you just paste the text result of `vim --version` into the question.

Comment: Sure, I didn't want to bloat the question

Comment: Can you try running `vim` without custom initialisations? i.e. with `vim -u NONE <filename>`. If it fixes the problem, you can try loading different `vimrc`s individually, with `vim -u ~/.vimrc <filename>`, `vim -u /etc/vimrc <filename>` (or wherever your system `vimrc`'s are kept).

Comment: @Sparhawk If I do not use any rc file it seems to work ok. Since in my home directory I do not have any .vimrc, It must be something in the /etc/vimrc file right?

Comment: I *think* that's the only other file used in initiation. What's in `/etc/vimrc`?

Comment: Updated, still I don't get where should be the problem

Comment: http://vi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your `/etc/vimrc` contents are the same as on my fedora 22. `~/.vim/vimrc` is another place to look. Perhaps you have the wrong terminal type. Try `TERM=dumb vim ...`.

Comment: the folder ```~/.vim/``` does not exist. With ```TERM=dumb``` seems to work as with ```vim -u NONE```. I forgot to mention that I am doing all this in an ssh session. I'll now update the question

Comment: Maybe something broken in `~/.viminfo`? I don't know what could cause this effect but it does get loaded when vim start.

Comment: @Net_Raider you didn't tag me, so I didn't get notifications. You could try temporary moving `/etc/vimrc` to be totally sure.

Comment: You can execute `:scriptnames` in vim to see all sourced scrips. Then you can see what is still sourced if you use `vim -u NONE ...`.